# Bottom bar on Android

Tags: android, layout

How can I have a layout where there is a view occupying most of the top of the screen and a bottom bar below it in the bottom of the screen without setting size for top view directly?

Comment: see this for a native bottom bar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019986/which-view-should-be-used-for-new-material-design-bottom-navigation/42119958#42119958

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the top View's `android:layout_weight` set to "1", then you can set your bottom View's height and the top View will take up all remaining space.  For example:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" />
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="25dip" />
```

(Of course, if there is content in the bottom View, you can just set the height to "wrap_content" and have it set its own size based on its contents.)