# How to implement bottom navigation tab as per the google new guideline

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-design-library, android-bottomnav

How to implement bottom navigation tab as per the google new guideline (Pure android). Is there any example.?

Ref: https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html

Comment: I've implemented BottomNavigationView in a best possible way. Please visit this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44967021/2412582

Answer (score 13):

[Here](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar) first custom solution as far as I know.

**UPDATE:**

Official [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) is out in Support lib 25.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the support library v25.

Add in your `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

Add the `BottomNavigationView` in your layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/mycolor"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/mycolor"/>
```

Then create a menu file (menu/bottom_navigation_menu.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/my_action1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/my_drawable"
        android:title="@string/text"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    ....
</menu>
```

Then add the listener:

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.my_action1:
                        //Do something...
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 10):

Now, [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) is added in design support lib v25.0.0  released on October 2016

Add `BottomNavigationView` into your xml file.

For ex. activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="priyank.patel.bottomnavigationdemo.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add xml for menu items into menu folder.

For ex. bottom_navigation_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_video"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_music_video_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_video"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_music"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Set `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` on `BottomNavigationView` in your activity class.

For ex. MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Fragment fragment;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = new FavouriteFragment();
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_favorites:
                            fragment = new FavouriteFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_video:
                            fragment = new VideoFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_music:
                            fragment = new MusicFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Checkout here for [BottomNavigation-Demo](https://github.com/1priyank1/BottomNavigation-Demo)

Answer (score 5):

There are no code examples out there. Although there are custom libraries which can do the job as of now.(as mentioned in the posts above)
I would not recommend using TabLayout to achieve this, since in the design guidelines for Bottom Navigation Tab its clearly mentioned that swiping the screen should not scroll pages horizontally. However, TabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView and its main motive is to facilitate scrolling, even though you can disable that, it won't be ideal.

Comment: I agree... Even when turning off swiping, there is no easy way to get rid of the slide like animation and have a fade in or slide up instead.

Answer (score 2):

As user6146138 said, https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar is a great implementation. And you can check out a great tutorial on it [here](http://androidgifts.com/tag/bottom-navigation/), which is really easy to follow and part 2 shows you how to use it with fragments attached.

Another nice implementation is https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation if you want to check it out. I don't know of any tutorial on it, but the instructions at the link are good enough IMO.

Comment: I tried using roughike but keep having the first tab auto-selected - any idea why?

Comment: @Lion789 Do you mean initially? Or always?
Do you not want the first tab to be initially selected?
Can you describe the issue in more detail, please.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there are no code examples and the Bottom bar is not in the support library (yet). I have found a third party library that mimics the guidelines though. It can be found [here](https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar).

Answer (score 1):

**Repository** I have added complete project at this link have a look
https://gitlab.com/ashish29agre/android-bottom-navigation-view-support-lib

Hi This might be little late here is the xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nm_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/nm_bottom"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: "layout_behavior" should be in RelativeLayout, and "layout_scrollFlags" doesn't work with BottomNavigationView

Comment: Its working for me check my answer at https://gitlab.com/ashish29agre/android-bottom-navigation-view-support-lib

Answer (score 1):

You can use google design support libraries for [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html). Read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36032177/android-new-bottom-navigation-bar).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) for that. It can be easily aligned at bottom of screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are no code examples yet. But there are custom libraries in android arsenal and this is a detailed tutorial you can check it [Android material design bottom navigation](http://androidgifts.com/build-android-material-design-bottom-navigation/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no official example but check below link.
Very good implementation. 
https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar