# Android Bottom bar like Google Space app

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I want to use a BottomBar in my Android app but I'd like to style it like the [one in Google Space app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRyvl.jpg). How can I accomplish that effect?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019986/which-view-should-be-used-for-new-material-design-bottom-navigation/42119958#42119958

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after asking friend i found [this library](https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View) that implements exactly what i want

[Here is a Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrvej.png)

Comment: does not work how to solve the null pointer exception
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Your space item count must be greater than 1 , your current items count isa : 0`

Answer (score 2):

This library lets you use it like a tab layout [SpaceTabLibrary](https://github.com/thelong1EU/SpaceTabLayout).

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: it does not animate the icons

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (smoke and mirrors) solution would be to make a nine patch with a bump in the middle for that layout's background - e.g. use Roman's tool - https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html

If you need the bottom bar to be animated, then you'll definitely have to create your own. Perhaps do a custom layout and when drawing the background, draw a bump in the middle? Extravaganza would surely be animating a vector drawable: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html

Answer (score -2):

Some elements to implement your solution :

- Material Design > Components > [Bottom Navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#)
- Tutorials : http://androidgifts.com/tag/bottom-navigation/
- Custom implementation : https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

[image]

- Another custom implementation : https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

[image]

Comment: This isn't exactly what im asking for,i want it with the pump in the middle with the create button

Comment: @AhmedElshaer You need to custom your implementation with bottom bar i think. Nothing exists already fully realized

Comment: @AhmedElshaer Nice search, i had never seen before. Glad to know him