# how to add some Fragment into TabHost?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wrote some app that contain TabHost. 
Each tab contain a LinearLayout - and i want to add some different exist Fragment that i created to each of the tab

How to do it ?

```
private void setNewTab(Context context, TabHost tabHost, String tag, String title, int contentID ){
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag);

    tabSpec.setIndicator(title);


    Fragment newFragment = new ActionFragment ();


    tabSpec.setIndicator(newFragment.getView());


    tabSpec.setContent(contentID);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);                     // after this line i get an exception


}




<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 1 Content" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 2 Content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tab 3 Content" />
        </LinearLayout>


    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show the code you're working with

Comment: attached the code

Comment: you should use `ViewPager` instead of `LinearLayout`

Comment: Do you want to use Fragment inside other Fragment (tab)? Use getChildFragmentManager. U can still use fragments inside other fragments

Comment: Typically, you setup a TabLayout with a ViewPager and setup the ViewPager with a FragmentAdapter. At present, `newFragment.getView()` should be null because the Fragment was never inflated

Comment: amm ,... i still new on android develop. 

so maybe i don't understand it well - 

i want each tab ( i have 3 tabs ) will contain different fragment

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for TabLayout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` if you many tabs. If you have only 2 to 3 tabs use `PagerAdapter`.

Check out the below link, it explained very well how any why to use `ViewPager` with `TabLayout`.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

`TabLayout` with `ViewPager` goes well in your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search of "Android Fragment TabHost" into the documentation results in the [`FragmentTabHost` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html). Are you using it?

```
    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("action").setIndicator("action"), ActionFragment.class, null);
```

I still think TabLayout would be a easier option.

If you want tabs at the bottom, there's even options for that.

[Which view should be used for new Material Design Bottom Navigation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019986/which-view-should-be-used-for-new-material-design-bottom-navigation)