# Custom Bottom Navigation with Navigation Component

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I want to implement following bottom navigation:

[image]

I wanna use the Navigation Component too. So I need to use material bottom navigation, not third party libraries.

Do you have a suggestion implementing this bottom navigation **except adding custom libraies**?

Comment: https://proandroiddev.com/how-i-drew-custom-shapes-in-bottom-bar-c4539d86afd7. This shows how to use bezeir curves. In your case the curve is little different. You could start by reading the blog and see if you could come up with the exact curve at the center of bottom nav bar.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019986/which-view-should-be-used-for-new-material-design-bottom-navigation/42119958#42119958